# Sorting and filtering doesn't work in server-side processing mode

Tags: jquery, json, datatables

I am having an issue with my table. I am seeing "Processing" label frozen when I try to sort or paging, and I see that JSON is being generates fine, here is my table setup I know is heavy but I hope you can help me.

```
var dt =$('#mainDataOutputTable').DataTable( {
        bFilter:false,
        pageLength : 10,
        info: false,
        columnDefs: [ { orderable: false, targets: [7 ] }],
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
            ajax: {
                url: 'firstreport_ajax.cfm',
                type: 'POST'
            },
        colReorder: true,
        "columns": [
          { "data": "status"},
          { "data": "supervisor"},
          { "data": "type"},
          { "data": "date"},
          { "data": "shift"},
          { "data": "name"},
          { "data": "contract"},
          { "data": "desc"},
          { "data": "status"},
          { "data": "id"} ,
          { "data": "datecreated"}


          ]
    } );
```

and this is a sample JSON file

```
{
    "sEcho": 5,
    "iTotalRecords": 150,
    "iTotalDisplayRecords ": 150,
    "aaData": [
        {
            "status": "Open",
            "supervisor": "Ahmed",
            "type": "t",
            "date": "30-Jan-2014",
            "shift": "First",
            "name": " Anthony",
            "contract": "No",
            "desc": "test",
            "id": "1",
            "datecreated": "30-Jan-2014"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You have server-side processing enabled with `serverSide: true`, are you performing ordering/filtering/pagination on the server-side?

Comment: yes I am doing that, yes, it works fine, the JSON returns ordered or filtered as expected.

Comment: Add this `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true` before DataTables initialization and try if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using jQuery DataTables 1.10 but server-side processing parameters are from previous version of DataTables 1.9. See [this note](https://datatables.net/upgrade/1.10#Server-side-processing) about server-side processing when upgrading to 1.10.

Add `$.fn.dataTable.ext.legacy.ajax = true` before DataTables initialization code to force jQuery DataTables use old scheme.

Comment: after doing some adjustments, this worked very good! thank you!!

Comment: yeah it helped a lot, and Iam sorry, I am new on this and I need to learn how is the enviroment in stackoverflow! thanks again!